# How do I send a message on iMessage App Extension as a text in the input field?

Tags: ios, swift, imessage, imessage-extension

I have this iMessage app Extension with which when I press the data on the cell in the Table..this data would be sent. But i keep getting it in the format of a MessageTemplate. All I need is it to be sent as a normal text o n the input field. Please help!

I went through Apple Documentations and found out this function:

```
func insertText(_ text: String,completionHandler: ((Error?) -> Void)? = nil)
```

And This is my code:

```
 func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    print("cell selected at row \(indexPath.row)")

            let entry = filteredContacts[(indexPath as NSIndexPath).row]
            let name = entry.name
            let phone = entry.phone

            let layout = MSMessageTemplateLayout()
            layout.caption = name
            layout.subcaption =  score

            let message = MSMessage()
            message.layout = layout

    self.activeConversation?.insert(message, completionHandler: nil)
```

[This is how the message gets sent(The first part of the image) I want it to be sent as normal text( like the second part of the image):](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3FVJI.png)

Please Help!! Thanks in advance!

Comment: did you find any solution for it?

Comment: You are invoking the wrong method in order to send the text into the input filed. You found the right function: `insertText(_ text: String,completionHandler: ((Error?) -> Void)? = nil)`. But the method you are invoking in your table views delegate method is `func send(_ message: MSMessage, 
completionHandler: ((Error?) -> Void)? = nil)`. Have a look at the "Directly Sending a Message" section: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/messages/msconversation

Answer (score 0):

This is in objective-C but should be easy to translate. I got this to work for me by doing the following:

```
//Check if we have an active converstation.
if (self.activeConversation) {
    //Add the content to be sent as a text message.
    [self.activeConversation insertText:text_content completionHandler:nil];
}
```

Insert text put the text in my text_content into the iMessage field in plain text format. It did not automatically send, the user still has to hit the send button.

Answer (score -2):

you have to pass session in MSMessage

```
let session = MSSession()
let message = MSMessage(session: session)
```

Comment: You should provide more detail, like why this works, explain your code. The more detail the better.